# Can I open my application from Safari using custom URL scheme?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

Hey I was wondering if It is possible to add my own application to the UIActionSheet that opens up in safari when you press the share button on the bottom toolbar. I would like to take the user to my application if that button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to look at asking the user to add a bookmark in safari to your app.

Tweetie/Instapaper and Summly have similiar features that pass info using javascript to your app from safari bookmarks.

(correction - Tweetie had, not sure if Twitter still use it)

edit - javascript like this works.

> javascript:window.location=%27YOUR_CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME://%27+window.location

this takes the current safari url and passes it to your app and you can handle it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Comment: And how would the user do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to modify core applications like Safari, or any other application for that matter, from your own app (without using private APIs...).